# How can I pull gmail data with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, gmail

I'm essentially trying to create an application for myself that I can manage my emails etc. with Vue.js

I've managed to get authorisation working using an npm package called [vue-googleapis](https://github.com/ql4b/vue-googleapis)

However I am now trying to pull data from my (or the users) gmail account but running into some errors.

Here's my existing code in my component:

```
  <div class="gmail-init">
    <h1>Google APIs example - oAuth2 (vuex)</h1>
    <p>isReady: {{ gauthReady }}</p>
    <p>isSignedIn: {{ isSignedIn }}</p>
    <p v-if="isSignedIn && user">{{ user.getBasicProfile().getName() }}</p>
    <button :disabled="isSignedIn || !gauthReady" @click="signIn">Sign In</button>
    <button :disabled="!isSignedIn || !gauthReady" @click="signOut">Sign Out</button>
    <button :disabled="!isSignedIn || !gauthReady" @click="disconnect">Disconnect</button>

    <button :disabled="!isSignedIn || !gauthReady" @click="labels">Labels</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'GmailInit',
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('gauth', {
      gauthReady: 'isReady',
      isSignedIn: 'isSignedIn',
      user: 'getUser'
    })
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$store.dispatch('gauth/init')
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('gauth', {
      signIn: 'signIn',
      signOut: 'signOut',
      disconnect: 'disconnect'
    }),
    async labels () {
      console.log('labels called')
      const auth = this.isSignedIn
      // const response = await this.$google.api.client.youtube.playlists.list({
      const gmail = this.$google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth })
      const response = await gmail.users.labels.list({
        // mine: true
        userId: 'me'
        // part: "snippet",
      })

      const labels = response.data.labels
      if (labels.length) {
        console.log(response.result.items)
        labels.forEach((label) => {
          console.log(`- ${label.name}`)
        })
        // this.playlistItems = response.result.items
      } else {
        console.log('error')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and here's my code for the import (vuex/store)

```
const STATUS_LOADING = 'loading'
const STATUS_READY = 'ready'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    status: STATUS_LOADING,
    signedId: null,
    user: null,
    error: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setStatus (state, status) {
      state.status = status
    },
    setSignedIn (state, signedId) {
      state.signedId = signedId
    },
    setError (state, error) {
      state.error = error
    },
    setUser (state, user) {
      state.user = user
    }
  },
  actions: {
    init (context) {
      const google = this._vm.$google
      const load = setInterval(function () {
        if (google.isInit) {
          context.commit('setStatus', STATUS_READY)
          context.commit(
            'setSignedIn',
            google.api.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()
          )
          google.api.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(function (signedId) {
            context.commit('setSignedIn', signedId)
          })
          google.api.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.listen(function (user) {
            context.commit('setUser', user)
          })
          clearInterval(load)
        }
      })
    },
    async signIn (context) {
      try {
        await this._vm.$google.api.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn()
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        context.commit('setError', e.error)
      }
    },
    async signOut (context) {
      try {
        await this._vm.$google.api.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut()
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        context.commit('setError', e.error)
      }
    },
    async disconnect (context) {
      try {
        await this._vm.$google.api.auth2.getAuthInstance().disconnect()
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        context.commit('setError', e.error)
      }
    }
  },
  getters: {
    isReady (state) {
      return state.status === STATUS_READY
    },
    isSignedIn (state) {
      return state.signedId === true
    },
    getUser (state) {
      return state.user
    }
  }
}
```

the main function that isn't working:

```
async labels () {
      console.log('labels called')
      const auth = this.isSignedIn
      // const response = await this.$google.api.client.youtube.playlists.list({
      const gmail = this.$google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth })
      const response = await gmail.users.labels.list({
        // mine: true
        userId: 'me'
        // part: "snippet",
      })

      const labels = response.data.labels
      if (labels.length) {
        console.log(response.result.items)
        labels.forEach((label) => {
          console.log(`- ${label.name}`)
        })
        // this.playlistItems = response.result.items
      } else {
        console.log('error')
      }
    }
```